# Is there a way to search everything within the page from firebug?

Tags: firebug

Sometimes I dont know where a particular element exists. I just want to see it being referenced. Is there any other way other than going to each tab HTML, CSS, Script, DOM and Net? Also, there is a website that is using several images and I know their names and such, and I still can't find in the source code, so "search everywhere!" may come handy for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use firefinder with firebug

Reference: http://www.sitepoint.com/firefinder-adds-search-to-firebug/